# comparing the orders of complexity

Tags: algorithms

Suppose we have $f(n)=O(g(n))$.

Can we claim $f^2(n)=O(g^2(n))$ ? I need to use it in a proof and I think it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $f(n) = O(g(n))$ means that there exists some constant $C$ such that for all sufficiently large $n$ (say $n \ge N$), we have $|f(n)| \le C g(n)$.

This inequality $|f(n)| \le C g(n)$ gives $|f(n)|^2 \le C^2 g(n)^2$ for $n \ge N$, which is precisely the statement that $f(n)^2 = O(g(n)^2)$, namely that there exists a constant (in this case $C^2$) such that for all sufficiently large $n$, we have $|f(n)^2|$ bounded by that constant times $g(n)^2$.

[Note: I assume that by $f^2(n)$ and $g^2(n)$ you mean $f(n)^2$ and $g(n)^2$, not $f(f(n))$ and $g(g(n))$. If you meant the latter, then it's not true. For instance let $f(n) = 2^n$ and $g(n) = 2^n/2$, then $f(n) = O(g(n))$, but $f(f(n)) = 2^{2^n}$ and $g(g(n)) = 2^{2^n/2}/2 = \frac12 \sqrt{2^{2^n}}$ and it's not true that $f(f(n)) = O(g(g(n))$.